# Can I use a different grid system with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to use a different grid system such as semantic.gs with twitter bootstrap for layout purposes?

I guess I could try it, but i was hoping someone would have experience with it.

-- Adi

Comment: Why? To have more semantic html?

Comment: yes.. essentially, that is what appeals in that framework, at first impression.

Comment: Looking over the specs for semantic.gs -- it does seem nice. Keep in mind you can customize the grid for TBS. IMO -- I don't think having the multiple dependencies will really be an issue.

Comment: How did it work out for you? Thinking about doing the same; using Susy for responsive layout, but Bootstrap for components.

Comment: @Pedr I actually did not get a chance to work on this, yet. For my first prototype I ended up using a theme built on bootstrap, so I ended up going with that, for now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, but you might lose some advantages of Twitter Bootstrap, especially if you need to do responsive. You can create a page with your box layout and assign classes of another grid system to your divs and still use TB's form, typography, navigation and other classes. Probably you don't want to use the top navigation or footer parts because those are quite closely linked to the grid layout but even that would be possible.

The question is rather, do you really want to have multiple dependencies in your project? If you're not worried about that, go ahead!

Comment: Thanks!. Appreciate your answer.